# Matlab Histogram Creation

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution

I'm trying to create an histogram with a normal distribution fitting. I wrote the code but it keeps on saying: index exceeds matrix dimension. Here's the code:

```
sigma=handles.Ht(end);
        figure(1)
        x_min = min(handles.array);
        x_max = max(handles.array);
        x_full = linspace(x_min,x_max,100);
        x_partial = x_full(x_full < L);
        y_full = normpdf(x_full,mean(handles.array),sigma);
        y_partial = normpdf(x_partial,mean(handles.array),sigma);
        area(x_full,y_full,'FaceColor','b');
        hold on;
        area(x_partial,y_partial,'FaceColor','r');
        grid on;
        % Histogram data
        [count,bins] = hist(handles.array,30);
        % Scale bins
        num_returns = numel(handles.array);
        scale = (bins(2)-bins(1))*num_returns;
        % Plot full data set
        a = bar(bins,count/scale,'w');
        set(get(a,'Children'),'FaceAlpha',0.8)
        hold off;
        title(['Best Normal Fit of Returns. Red Indicates Returns Below VaR: ',num2str(L)],'FontWeight','bold');
        handles.matrici.Mdati=[handles.array, handles.Ht, handles.VaR_p];
        guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
```

Matlab says the error is the "area" function but I don't understand why.
Any Ideas?

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in area (line 98)
            set(h(1),'RefreshMode','auto');

Error in Var_final>inv_quantile (line 643)
        area(x_partial,y_partial,'FaceColor','r');

Error in Var_final>pushbutton_calcola_Callback (line 309)
inv_quantile(handles)

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Var_final (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)Var_final('pushbutton_calcola_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: Did you accidentally create a variable called `area` earlier in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This is part of a GUI
I didn't create it.

Comment: Then please provide the full error and the exact line at which it occurs

Comment: you can find it now on the main post

Comment: N =

     1   100


M =

     1   100

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error by providing `area` with empty vectors as inputs, I have a feeling that that is what you are doing somehow:

```
area([], [])
```

I suggest you print `size(x_partial)` and `size(y_partial)` to the screen to debug this.

Comment: N =

     1   100


M =

     1   100

Comment: Sorry I see the error is actually with the next `area` line, so probably `x_partial = x_full(x_full < L);` returns an empty matrix